# How do I average my data into different time groups?

Tags: group-by, sqlite

My temperature data is inserted into the database every second.

Data sample:

```
Date                 Name  Value
-------------------  ----  -----
2016-09-29 12:46:30  T1    23.05
2016-09-29 12:46:30  T2    23.45
2016-09-29 12:46:30  T3    24.15
2016-09-29 12:46:31  T1    23.10
2016-09-29 12:46:31  T2    24.15
2016-09-29 12:46:31  T3    25.30
2016-09-29 12:46:32  T1    23.20
2016-09-29 12:46:32  T2    24.55
2016-09-29 12:46:32  T3    25.85
```

I want to select data for an hour, so that I get results like this:

```
Date                 Name  Value
-------------------  ----  -------
2016-09-29 12:46:30  T1    23.0678
2016-09-29 12:46:30  T2    23.4689
2016-09-29 12:46:30  T3    24.3056
2016-09-29 13:46:30  T1    23.1555
2016-09-29 13:46:30  T2    24.2222
2016-09-29 13:46:30  T3    25.4567
2016-09-29 14:46:30  T1    23.4532
2016-09-29 14:46:30  T2    24.5672
2016-09-29 14:46:30  T3    25.8999
```

This works for any one temperature:

```
SELECT Name, Date avg(Value) FROM tSeconds 
WHERE (Name = 'T1') AND 
Date BETWEEN '2016-09-20 12:46:30' AND '2016-09-29 14:46:30' 
GROUP BY strftime("%M", Date);
```

Please can you help me.

Comment: `12:46 to 14:46` is not an hour,also please tag the RDBMS you are using like SQLServer.Oracle,Mysql,Postgre..

Comment: Remove the 'Name' in the Select statement, since you don't have it in your Group By and you have 'T1' in your Where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Each non-aggregated column must be included in the group by. So you need to include "Name" in your group by.

Also, select the date using an hourly syntax for your strftime function, and use the same criterion in your group by declaration.

I'm assuming you're looking for hourly data here, so your query will be something like:

```
select strftime("%Y-%m-%M %H:46:30", Date), Name, avg(value)
from tSeconds 
where Date between '2016-09-29 12:46:30' and '2016-09-29 14:46:30'
group by strftime("%Y-%m-%M %H:46:30", Date), Name;
```

Comment: Andrew, this almost worked. The only problem is that it gave all results from the database between 12:46 and 14:46 ignoring the 29th. I need the 'where' statement so that the user can select which sensors to view. Using my original code, but adding 'Name' to the 'group by' gave me the correct results but with unsorted dates. So I have added 'by order of Date' to the end.